# c++ recursive template resolution: flattening vectors of vectors elegantly

Tags: c++, templates, vector

Consider the following (naive) piece of C++ code to transfer objects from a custom list type into a `std::vector`

```
template<class A> void transfer(std::vector<A>& target, const custom_list_type& source){
  for(const A& elem:source){
    target.push_back(elem);
  }
}
```

Now, imagine one had a `std::vector` of such custom lists and would want to flatten the structure, or a `std::vector` of such vectors. Naively, I would now go ahead and write functions of this type.

```
template<class A> void flatten_transfer(std::vector<A>& target, const std::vector<custom_list_type>& source){
  for(const auto& elem:source){
    flat_transfer(target,elem);
  }
}

template<class A> void flatten_transfer(std::vector<A>& target, const std::vector<std::vector<custom_list_type> >& source){
  for(const auto& elem:source){
    flat_transfer(target,elem);
  }
}
```

And so on and so forth. But I see that this is not very elegant, because I need a version of this function of every depth level. I would imagine there is a more elegant way to solve this using some template magic, but I'm not really knowledgeable enough to come up with a solution that is genuinely nicer.

What would be the "recommended" way to abstract away the vector-depth-level using templates, such that only a single instance of `flatten_transfer` would need to be written?

Comment: ot: the most elegant way is to not use deeply nested containers in the first place ;)

Comment: the input is always a `std::vector` ? Or you also need other container types?

Comment: Given that `source` can be iterated over with the range-based for, the `transfer()` function can be implemented as `target.insert(target.end(), source.begin(), source.end())`.    The same can be used with the body of your first `flatten_transfer()` function.   Doing it for the third from there is trivial.

Comment: @user463035818: the input is always a `std::vector`

Comment: @Peter: thanks for the suggestion, which is actually quite useful, but doesn't address the core part of this question (how the two variants of `flatten_transfer` can be extended and unified).

Comment: Look up template specialisation (in this case, partial specialisation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that I correctly understand the problem, the following function template well works for this purpose in C++17 and over.
This function instantiates `target.push_back(elem)` if and only if `A` is same with `B`.
Otherwise, this goes to the next depth:

[**Live DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pMYgWLB4cBTt5C0h)

```
template<
    class A,
    class B,
    template <class...> class Container,
    class... extras>
void flat_transfer(std::vector<A>& target, const Container<B, extras...>& source)
{
    for(const auto& elem : source)
    {
        if constexpr(std::is_same<A, B>::value){
            target.push_back(elem);
        }
        else{
            flat_transfer(target, elem);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an usage example:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
std::set<std::vector<std::deque<int>>, std::greater<>> vv{{{4,5}, {6,7}, {8,9}}, {{10,11,12}, {13,14}, {15}}};

flat_transfer(v, vv);

// prints "1 2 3 10 11 12 13 14 15 4 5 6 7 8 9" 
for(const auto& i : v){
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```